# HttpPut with route controller

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi i need some help I'm trying to send some data with ajax to a controller using PUT Method to do update here is the javascript and ajax code:

```
function UpdateProduct() {
var id = location.pathname.split('/')[2];

var product = {
    Name: $("#txtName").val(),
    Description: $("#txtDescription").val(),
    Price: $("#txtPrice").val(),
    SubCategoryId: $("#txtSubCategoryId").val(),
    CompanyId: $("#txtSubCategoryId").val(
    ProductCode: $("#ProductCode").val(
    Barcode: $("#Barcode").val(
    Brand: $("#txtBrand").val(),
    Material: $("#txtMaterial").val(),
    Date: $("#txtDate").val(),
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/UpdateProduct/"+id,
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: "json",
    data: product,
    success: function (result) {
        alert('Successful');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});
```

};

and my controller code:

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("UpdateProduct/{id}")]
    public void UpdateProduct(int id, ProductsBE product)
    {
        var api = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"];
        var productsById = new ProductsRep();
        var searchResponse = productsById.UpdateProduct(product,id, api);
    }
```

The API is working because i have tested it with postman.

Comment: It seems like you haven't even tried to debug this yourself because you've given us nearly no information.... For instance, when you executed the javascript did the browser try to send the request? what Url did the browser request? was the post body of the request in the correct format? etc. Give us an example of the request the browser sends with javascript - and find out how it differs from the request from the postman request etc.

Comment: so are you getting null?

Comment: ajax doesn't even call the controller its only alerting the error message ... the url is correct because i tested it too with this code:                    complete: function () {
            alert(this.url)
        },

Comment: Give us that error message, obviously.

Comment: here is the error I'm getting from the alert: http://i.imgur.com/QmsPbVW.png

Comment: doesnt it go to the error(e) function?

Comment: why not use post?

Comment: post is not for updating data ....

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `JSON.stringify` to convert your object `product` to `json` string

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/UpdateProduct/"+id,
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(product),
    success: function (result) {
        alert('Successful');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you check the response by pressing f12 and in networks tab